# how to get multiple arguments using getopt in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to get multiple value passed with one option in command using getopts in shell script.

Example

> sample -a 0 -p 1 -t 1 2 3

How can i get all three arguments passed with -t option using getopts in bash shell script?

Comment: Is `sample -a 0 -p 1 -t 1 -t 2 -t 3 -a xyz` an option? As most people used to console commands i'd never expect 2 and 3 to belong to -t unless i had them quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You must use quotes:

```
sample -a 0 -p 1 -t "1 2 3"
```

#### UPDATE: (As per comments below OP cannot use quotes since string is coming form user)

Here is a script that takes whole command line argument and reconstructs it after inserting right quotes (assuming only `getopts` type switches are being used):

```
#!/bin/bash
# surround all arguments values by double quotes
args="$(sed -r 's/(-[A-Za-z]+ )([^-]*)( |$)/\1"\2"\3/g' <<< $@)"
# create an array from prepared string
declare -a a="($args)"
# prepare positional arguments for getopts
set - "${a[@]}"

# rest of the getopts script follows
while getopts "e:d:c:ab" optionName; do
   echo "-$optionName is present [$OPTARG]"
done
```

#### TEST:

```
./opts.sh -c ccc -d d1 d2 d3 -e egg hunt -a
-c is present [ccc]
-d is present [d1 d2 d3]
-e is present [egg hunt]
-a is present []
```

#### Online Demo: http://ideone.com/KwnNms

Comment: Is there any other solution without using quote?

Comment: What is the problem in using quotes? If you're using shell scripting quotes are essential to use.

Comment: I can not use quote in this command because it is user friendly command which is given by user. Command format is without quote and i want to access using OPTARG and OPTIND.

Comment: Is there any way to access those three variable using any tricks from getopt command?

Comment: If you send unquoted string then your script will treat as separate arguments. If you provide the way your are getting arguments then probably I can suggest some way out.

Comment: I am getting command like "sample -a 0 -p 1 -t 1 2 3" and i want to access all arguments of -t option. This is just command as we are using linux command with multiple arguments without any quote.

Comment: Ok can you also get like this `sample -a 0 -p 1 -t 1 2 3 -a xyz`?

Comment: yes. that -t option can be written in any position in command

Comment: Please let me know if you have any other idea about how to solve this issue?

Comment: Only other way is to not use `getopts` at all and get full argument list as `$@` and then process it inside the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can you **[shift](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html)** command in your script:

For example:

```
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
        -a ) shift
        #do somethings with 0
                ;;
        -p ) shift
        #do somethings with 1
                ;;
        -t ) shift
        #do somethings with all of the numbers after -t
        ;;
        * ) #usage
            exit 1
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: How can i access all arguments after -t option? Because position of -t option is not fixed. it can varied from first option to last option.

Comment: You can use a while command to detect number (Ex. integers) in -t case like:
while [[ $1 ~= ^[+-]?[0-9]+$ ]]; do <do_somethings>; shift; done